# node.js error: throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event. listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem with uploading binary data to my server running node.js Express.

This is my code for the post function:
[image]

And this is the error message in terminal:

[image]

I cant find any unhandled errors tho..

Thankful for any help in the right direction! :)

Comment: Your unhandled error event *is* `Error: listen EADDRINUSE`.

Comment: there's a process running on that host that's already listening on that port

Comment: Aaa shit, came to the same conclusion after googling, but wasn't sure.. Seems that I created a screen with another instance before.. Thanks guys!

Comment: Note: Please include code snippets and text output as text within posts. They can be formatted and highlighted as code blocks using the `{}` button in the editor. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code